# I don't understand how react router works

Tags: reactjs

I want to create separate containers for all my react components. For now
App.js looks like this:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import routesConstants from "./config/routesConstants";
import ContainerBlock from "./components/login-and-register/container/ContainerBlock";
import DashboardContainer from "./components/dashboard/container/DashboardContainer";

function App() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path={routesConstants.root} component={ContainerBlock}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default App;
```

But I want react router redirects user from / to my container, so I did this in my ContainerBlock:

```
import React from "react";
import LoginPage from "../login-page/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "../register-page/RegisterPage";
import RootPage from "../root-page/RootPage";
import {Switch, Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom"
import routesConstants from "../../../config/routesConstants";

const ContainerBlock = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container-block">
            <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from={routesConstants.root} to={routesConstants.welcome_page} />
                <Route path={routesConstants.welcome_page} component={RootPage} />
                <Route path={routesConstants.user.LOGIN} component={LoginPage} />
                <Route path={routesConstants.user.REGISTER} component={RegisterPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContainerBlock
```

And there are three components and redirects between these three works fine, but when I try to access /dashboard from LoginPage or RegisterPage - nothing happens, but if I move dashboard component to ContainerBlock switch - it works. I'm new to react and react router. How can I solve this problem? Maybe there is other way to build react app

**EDIT:**

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/index";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Router>
                <App/>
            </Router>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

My routesConstants file:

```
const routesConstants = {
    root: '/',
    welcome_page: '/welcome',
    user: {
        LOGIN: '/login',
        REGISTER: '/register',
    },
    dashboard: {
        INDEX: '/dashboard'
    }
}

export default routesConstants
```

Comment: Can you post code for your `routesConstants` import and where you are rendering your `App` component please?

Comment: @MikeAbeln I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) for the `switch` statement

It renders the ***first*** route that matches only and since your routes always start with `"/"` and `exact` is not used on that route it will always render the `ContainerBlock`

Look at your **App.js**:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import routesConstants from "./config/routesConstants";
import ContainerBlock from "./components/login-and-register/container/ContainerBlock";
import DashboardContainer from "./components/dashboard/container/DashboardContainer";

function App() {
    return (
        // switch only renders the first match
        <Switch>
            {/* first match is always '/' path... it will always match */}
            <Route path={routesConstants.root} component={ContainerBlock}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Try adding `exact` to your first route in **App.js**:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import routesConstants from "./config/routesConstants";
import ContainerBlock from "./components/login-and-register/container/ContainerBlock";
import DashboardContainer from "./components/dashboard/container/DashboardContainer";

function App() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path={routesConstants.root} exact component={ContainerBlock}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default App;
```

There may be many more things for you to do to reach your intended concept.
This is just the first logic + documentation blocker in your code.

Comment: I've tried your solution. But now all my routes doesn't render components